# Combing two sql queries into one grouping

Tags: sqlite

So I have the following two queries at the bottom. Now how could I would combine them in one table? Also So it be:

```
+-------+-----------------+----------------+
| Date  | Tickets created | Tickets closed |
+-------+-----------------+----------------+
| 10/25 |              50 |             45 |
| 10/26 |              40 |             40 |
| 10/27 |              30 |             30 |
| 10/28 |              10 |              0 |
+-------+-----------------+----------------+
```

The tickets table looks like this:

```
+----+----------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| id |      created_at      |      closed_at       | master_ticket_id |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+------------------+
|  1 | 2013-10-12 00:00:00' | 2013-10-12 06:00:00' |                  |
|  2 | 2013-11-11 00:00:00' |                      |                  |
|  3 | 2013-11-12 00:00:00' |                      |                2 |
|  4 | 2013-11-13 10:00:00' | 2013-11-13 12:00:00' |                  |
|  5 | 2013-12-12 00:00:00' | 2013-12-12 07:00:00' |                  |
+----+----------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Query #1

```sql
select strftime("%m-%d",tickets.created_at) as 'Date',
count(tickets.created_at)as 'Tickets created'
from tickets 
WHERE tickets.created_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' 
and tickets.created_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00'
and tickets.master_ticket_id is Null
Group by strftime("%m-%d",tickets.created_at)
```

Which produces:

```sql
+-------+-----------------+
| Date  | Tickets created |
+-------+-----------------+
| 10/25 |              50 |
| 10/26 |              40 |
| 10/27 |              30 |
+-------+-----------------+
```

Query #2

```sql
select strftime("%m-%d",tickets.closed_at) as 'Date',
count(tickets.closed_at)as 'Tickets closed'
from tickets 
WHERE tickets.closed_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' 
and tickets.closed_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00'
and tickets.master_ticket_id is Null
Group by strftime("%m-%d",tickets.closed_at)
```

Which produces:

```sql
+-------+----------------+
| Date  | Tickets closed |
+-------+----------------+
| 10/25 |             50 |
| 10/26 |             40 |
| 10/27 |             30 |
+-------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited because previous version had some faults]

It appears to be more difficult to avoid a `UNION` than I'd hoped, but as far as I'v etested the following should work.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(created) AS 'Tickets created', SUM(closed) AS 'Tickets closed' FROM
(
    SELECT strftime("%m-%d",tickets.created_at) AS 'Date',
    COUNT(tickets.created_at) AS 'created', 
    0 AS 'closed'
    FROM tickets 
    WHERE tickets.created_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' 
    AND tickets.created_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00'
    AND tickets.master_ticket_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY Date

UNION ALL

    SELECT strftime("%m-%d",tickets.closed_at) AS 'Date',
    0 AS 'created',  
    COUNT(tickets.closed_at) AS 'closed'
    FROM tickets 
    WHERE tickets.closed_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00' 
    AND tickets.closed_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00'
    AND tickets.master_ticket_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY Date
)
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: This one is pretty close to what I wanted. Only problem is that when I change tickets.created_at and tickets.closed_at to the days in December for this month, it still shows November, and October etc, despite it being 0 for Tickets created and 0 for Tickets closed.

Comment: Ah, well, you could add a term in the where clause to select only those with a creation-date in between certain dates. Or perhaps an `OR` of the two terms we now sum over.

Comment: Hmm that's what I thought too but when I added the line after the where statement:"AND tickets.created_at >= '2013-12-01 00:00:00' AND tickets.created_at < '2013-12-30 00:00:00'"
It is returning the correct dates but '0' for all the tickets.created and tickets.closed

Comment: Hmm, actually, the `Date` shouldn't be based on `created_at` in case of closed tickets, should it. I'll think about it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try JOIN tables, like:

```
      SELECT *
      FROM (query1) q1
      LEFT JOIN (query) q2
      ON q1.date = q2.date
```

but mySql has no Full Join, and the result will not be good. You must use, combination LEFT + RIGHT JOIN and result is UNION of 2 queries.

But try this (not tested):

```
 SELECT 
     strftime("%m-%d",`date`) AS `date`, 
     SUM(created) `created`, 
     SUM(closed)`closed`
  FROM
  (
     SELECT 
     CASE
         WHEN (tickets.created_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00'  and tickets.created_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00'  and tickets.master_ticket_id is Null )  THEN created_at
         WHEN (tickets.closed_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00'  and tickets.closed_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00' and tickets.master_ticket_id is Null)  THEN closed_at
         END AS `date` ,    
     CASE
         WHEN (tickets.closed_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00'  and tickets.closed_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00' and tickets.master_ticket_id is Null) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS `closed`,
     CASE
          WHEN (tickets.created_at >= '2013-10-01 00:00:00'  and tickets.created_at< '2013-10-31 00:00:00'  and tickets.master_ticket_id is Null) THEN 1
          ELSE 0
          END AS `created`
     FROM tickets 
 ) AS results
 Group by strftime("%m-%d",`date`)
```

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid SQL - no such function: IF" Does Sqllite not support if statements??

Comment: The format is correct just that the value it is returning is slightly off in comparison to the original queries I use. I'll try and take a look at it to see why. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think the count may be off because if a ticket is created and closed in the given interval, both created and closed are counted on the created date (instead on the respective dates).

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not give the sample data and structures, and did not want to create them yourself...;)

Comment: I added what the tickets table looks like. :)

Comment: Yes, my query is bad :(. Can't do this that. If ticket is created and closed in same mounth, then is counted as 'created'. @towr's query is ok.